# Identifying graphs in heap of connected nodes -- how is this called?

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph

I have a SQL table with three columns X, Y, Z. I need to split it in groups in such a way that all records with same value of X or Y or Z are assigned to the same group. I need to make sure that the records with same value X or Y or Z are never split across multiple groups.

If you think of records as nodes and values of X, Y, Z as edges, this problem is the same as finding all graphs where the nodes in each graph will be connected directly or indirectly via X, Y, or Z-edge, but each graph will have no edges in common with other graphs (otherwise it would be part of the same graph).

A few years ago I knew what this was called and even remembered the algorithm but now it escapes me. Please tell me how this problem is called so I can Google for solution. If you now a good algorithm -- please point me to it. If you have a SQL implementation -- I will marry you :)

Example:

```
    X                   Y               Z            BUCKET
---------     ----------------      ---------      -----------
   1                   34              56              1
   54                  43              45              2
   1                   12              22              1
   2                   34              11              1
```

The last row is in bucket 1 because of the value of Y=34 which is the same as of the first row, which is in bucket 1.

Comment: Are you talking about the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause?

Comment: @Oded I'm not sure how to treat your comment, whether as a joke or an offence, but given your 48k rep I will treat it as a joke. Added an example for those who prefer picture to thousand words.

Comment: No offense meant - different users have different levels of knowledge for different technologies. I don't assume knowledge unless the question demonstrates it. I assumed your SQL was not very good... I am also finding the question difficult to understand and somewhat vague, hence my comment.

Comment: is it correct in your example that x=2 is in bucket = 1?

Comment: @Randy, absolutely, it is in the bucket 1 due to the value of Y being 34 which is the same value of Y as the first record has

Comment: Side note: This reminds me of thought experiment where all people in the world linked  if there is a chain of people between you and the other person who had sex. THe theorem was that there might be a few isolated nodes, but that most of the world is in this way connected.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be looking for Strongly-Connected Components within that graph? EDIT: or rather, a maximal connected component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks not like a graph, more like a [simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex).
But if we treat this complex as its skeletal graph (the numbers are treated as vertices and a row in a table means that all that three vertices are connected by an edge), then we may just use any algorithm to find [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of this graph. I'm not sure whether there is a feasible way to do this in SQL though, perhaps it would be more prudent to use a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) somehow.

However, for this specific problem there may be some easy solution attainable by means of SQL which I didn't look for.

Comment: Connected component is the keyword! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to find how many nodes in each group x:

```
select x, count(x) 
from mytable
group by x
```

or to find the list of sets x:

```
select distinct x from mytable;
```

Comment: All the values of X do not represent the complete group. The group also includes all the values of Y that match any of the values of Y in the records with the same value of X. And so on, recursively for all other values of X, Y and Z.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initially `GROUP BY` one of the colums (say X), make buckets, then do so for Y and Z, each time merging all the buckets from the previous step if you find new groups.

Repeat the process for X, Y, and Z until the buckets stop changing.

Are you working for linked-in or facebook? :)