# How do I efficiently create logical subsets of data in a many-to-many mapping table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, many-to-many, aggregate-functions

I have a many-to-many relationship between invoices and credit card transactions, which I'm trying to map sums of together.  The best way to think of the problem is to imagine TransactionInvoiceMap as a bipartite graph.  For each connected subgraph, find the total of all invoices and the total of all transactions within that subgraph.  In my query, I want to return the values computed for each of these subgraphs along with the transaction ids they're associated with.  Totals for related transactions should be identical.

More explicitly, given the following transactions/invoices

```
Table: TransactionInvoiceMap
TransactionID  InvoiceID
1              1
2              2
3              2
3              3

Table: Transactions
TransactionID  Amount
1              $100
2              $75
3              $75

Table: Invoices
InvoiceID  Amount
1          $100
2          $100
3          $50
```

my desired output is

```
TransactionID  TotalAsscTransactions TotalAsscInvoiced
1              $100                  $100
2              $150                  $150
3              $150                  $150
```

Note that invoices 2 and 3 and transactions 2 and 3 are part of a logical group.

Here's a solution (simplified, names changed) that apparently works, but is very slow.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to optimize this, but I think it would involve eliminating the subqueries into TransactionInvoiceGrouping.  Feel free to suggest something radically different.

```
with TransactionInvoiceGrouping as (
    select 
        -- Need an identifier for each logical group of transactions/invoices, use
        -- one of the transaction ids for this.
        m.TransactionID,
        m.InvoiceID,
        min(m.TransactionID) over (partition by m.InvoiceID) as GroupingID
    from TransactionInvoiceMap m
)
select distinct
    g.TransactionID,
    istat.InvoiceSum as TotalAsscInvoiced,
    tstat.TransactionSum as TotalAsscTransactions
from TransactionInvoiceGrouping g
    cross apply (
        select sum(ii.Amount) as InvoiceSum
        from (select distinct InvoiceID, GroupingID from TransactionInvoiceGrouping) ig
            inner join Invoices ii on ig.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID
        where ig.GroupingID = g.GroupingID
    ) as istat
    cross apply (
        select sum(it.Amount) as TransactionSum
        from (select distinct TransactionID, GroupingID from TransactionInvoiceGrouping) ig
            left join Transactions it on ig.TransactionID = it.TransactionID
        where ig.GroupingID = g.GroupingID
        having sum(it.Amount) > 0
    ) as tstat
```

Comment: They're grouped because they all "touch" each other.  If you drew lines for each relation, there would be a graph covering the four objects.  I thought there was a mathy name for this kind of grouping, but I can't remember it.

Comment: @StuartBranhan - So, they are grouped because they have a common invoice?, is that how this works?. And is only for that reason that you are suming $150 as the total transactions amount, because you are adding the amount from transaction 2 and transaction 3?

Comment: Yes, or if there's a common transaction.  The graph metaphor works best to explain it.  Did you write the previous comment that I responded to? Probably a good idea to keep comments so that they end up making sense for later readers.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to edit my comment and ended up deleting it, I can't undelete it actually

Comment: Fair enough :) This is a really tough one - both to explain and solve.

Comment: I think you're looking to divide the graph represented by this data into **connected components**, in which case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688281/identifying-graphs-in-heap-of-connected-nodes-how-is-this-called is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented the solution in a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28SQL.105%29.aspx):

```
;with TranGroup as (
    select TransactionID
        , InvoiceID as NextInvoice
        , TransactionID as RelatedTransaction
        , cast(TransactionID as varchar(8000)) as TransactionChain
    from TransactionInvoiceMap
    union all
    select g.TransactionID
        , m1.InvoiceID
        , m.TransactionID
        , g.TransactionChain + ',' + cast(m.TransactionID as varchar(11))
    from TranGroup g
        join TransactionInvoiceMap m on g.NextInvoice = m.InvoiceID
        join TransactionInvoiceMap m1 on m.TransactionID = m1.TransactionID
    where ',' + g.TransactionChain + ',' not like '%,' + cast(m.TransactionID as varchar(11)) + ',%'
)
, RelatedTrans as (
    select distinct TransactionID, RelatedTransaction
    from TranGroup
)
, RelatedInv as (
    select distinct TransactionID, NextInvoice as RelatedInvoice
    from TranGroup
)
select TransactionID
    , (
        select sum(Amount)
        from Transactions
        where TransactionID in (
            select RelatedTransaction
            from RelatedTrans
            where TransactionID = t.TransactionID
        )
    ) as TotalAsscTransactions
    , (
        select sum(Amount)
        from Invoices
        where InvoiceID in (
            select RelatedInvoice
            from RelatedInv
            where TransactionID = t.TransactionID
        )
    ) as TotalAsscInvoiced
from Transactions t
```

There is probably some room for optimization (including object naming on my part!) but I believe I have at least a correct solution which will gather all possible Transaction-Invoice relations to include in the calculations.

I was unable to get the existing solutions on this page to give the OP's desired output, and they got uglier as I added more test data.  I'm not sure if the OP's posted "slow" solution is correct as stated.  It's very possible that I'm misinterpreting the question.

**Additional info:**

I've often seen that recursive queries can be slow when working with large sets of data.  Perhaps that can be the subject of another SO question.  If that's the case, things to try on the SQL side might be to limit the range (add `where` clauses), index base tables, select the CTE into a temp table first, index that temp table, think of a better stop condition for the CTE...but profile first, of course.

Comment: Strange, I got incorrect results with the query I posted as well.  I must have simplified it incorrectly.  There's a lesson to try it out on table variables first. ;)  Will let you know how it goes with your code.

Comment: After playing with it some, your solution seems much more correct than what we currently have.  It's still really slow, but I think some tweaking and UI changes on the frontend could make it work.  I'll update this answer with a final solution later.  Recursive CTEs are really hard to get your head around. >_>

Comment: I'm glad it got you started.  I've added just a few possibilities for improving this.  Can't wait to see your final answer, and I appreciate the accept+bounty.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question right, I think you are trying to find the minimum of transaction id for each invoice and I have used ranking function to do the same.

```
WITH TransactionInvoiceGrouping AS (
SELECT 
    -- Need an identifier for each logical group of transactions/invoices, use
    -- one of the transaction ids for this.
    m.TransactionID,
    m.InvoiceID,       
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.InvoiceID ORDER BY m.TransactionID ) AS recno
FROM TransactionInvoiceMap m
)
 SELECT 
g.TransactionID,
istat.InvoiceSum AS TotalAsscInvoiced,
tstat.TransactionSum AS TotalAsscTransactions
 FROM TransactionInvoiceGrouping g
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(ii.Amount) AS InvoiceSum
    FROM TransactionInvoiceGrouping ig
        inner JOIN Invoices ii ON ig.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID
    WHERE ig.TransactionID = g.TransactionID
    AND ig.recno = 1
) AS istat
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT sum(it.Amount) AS TransactionSum
    FROM TransactionInvoiceGrouping ig
        LEFT JOIN transactions it ON ig.TransactionID = it.TransactionID
    WHERE ig.TransactionID = g.TransactionID
    AND ig.recno = 1
    HAVING SUM(it.Amount) > 0
) AS tstat

WHERE g.recno = 1
```